# Check if a JQuery mobile checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have a list of Checkboxes & I want to get the status of each one of them. 
The List is here :

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
       <input type="checkbox" name="Sunday" id="Sunday-1" class="custom" />
       <label for="Sunday-1">Sunday</label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Monday" id="Monday-1" class="custom" />
       <label for="Monday-1">Monday</label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Tuesday" id="Tuesday-1" class="custom" />
       <label for="Tuesday-1">Tuesday</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I usually Check the checkbox's status using this quote:

`var isChecked =  $('#CheckboxID').is(':checked');`

But in my case now, is there a method to get the status of "Jquery Mobile" checkboxes all at once ?

Comment: A list as in an array? Or you want them appended to the document as a `<ul><li></li><ul>` etc?

Comment: From jquerymobile version 1.3, see answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031831/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-in-jquery-mobile-fails

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do

```
var status = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.custom').map(function(){
    return $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

});
```

Then the `status array` will have an entry for each checkbox in the same order, `0` for unchecked and `1` for checked. It's not much of useful as you have no other information of the checkbox in the array.

If you want to perform operation based on the `status` you can use `.each()` instead, like

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.custom').each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     // perform operation for checked
   }
   else{
     // perform operation for unchecked
   }

});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to build an `array of objects` with the `name and status` of the checkboxes you can do that with

```
var status = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter('.custom').map(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
         return { 'name':name, 'status' : 'Checked'}; 
    else
        return { 'name':name, 'status' : 'UnChecked'};

});

console.log(status);​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/rL3Ze/

Read more on [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map)

Comment: That, fine sir, is a sexy answer.

Comment: Thanks a million ... a very helpful answer.

Comment: @SanaJoseph, You are most welcome, Glad to be able to help. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a question, when I use your code with jquery 1.7.1 it's not recognized & the status part is skipped, do you know what it the solution ?

Comment: @SanaJoseph, if you check console on this page http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/rL3Ze/1/show/, you will see it's logging the objects and view the source, it's using `1.7.1`

Comment: It's working now, seems that there is something wrong with the library I have, thanks again, sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 3):

I have this code. I think you should adjust to your case.

```
  $('#formfriends input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked'))
     //$(this).attr('disabled' , true);
     // do what you want here
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use jQuery each function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

.each function will help you to traverse through your checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

for jQm 1.3 i had to check for the class on the label in the wrapper div

- ui-checkbox-off
- ui-checkbox-on

samplecode (already rendered by jQm):

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
  <label data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="checkbox-off" data-theme="a" data-mini="false" class="ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">
        myLabel
      </span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-off ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="flip-num" class="flip-num">
</div>
```